# Using tenses correctly

Tags: grammar, tense

Someone told me that this sentence is wrong. I considered it but I don't think so.
Is this sentence incorrect please? Why?

> *Jaime would help you yesterday but he had to work.*

**EDIT**:
This sentence seems correct to me and it has the meaning below:

> *Jaime had the desire/intention of helping you (or he afforded to help you), but since he had to work, he didn't/couldn't do that.*

If you think of the sentence as incorrect, how to correct it please?

Comment: They just said it's wrong. I disagree because I see no issue with it.

Comment: It's ungrammatical but I'm on the fence about flagging it as proofreading.

Comment: Instead of an answer, I'll give you a hint: look up the past unreal conditional. Your sentence has an implicit *if*-clause.

Comment: Whoever _they_ are, they are right, and you should listen to and learn from them. Of course it is incorrect. If you think not, you need to learn about _conditionals_ in English. _"I would help you yesterday."_ Does that also seem correct to you?

Comment: @userr2684291: **Jaime would help you if he hadn't to work.**

Comment: It's by no way conditional. Guys, please pay more attention.

Comment: It's absolutely a conditional. And if you would like help here, you'd do well to be a bit more polite.

Comment: "Pay attention" to **[this link](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm)**. Please tell us if this sentence seems correct to you: _"I would help you yesterday but I can't."_

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to explain _in your question_ (not in a comment) why you believe the cited sentence is correct. Without more detail, we can't provide a useful answer. Please read our [**Details, Please**](https://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post.

Comment: userr2684291 basically gave you a very solid hint as to what is wrong with this sentence.  The past unreal conditional is exactly what the sentence is trying to use.  Another hint:  `Jaime would help you` isn't the proper way to construct a past unreal conditional.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to say this is with the modal "would have" to indicate *lost opportunity*:

> Jaime **would have helped** you, but he had to work.

This implies that Jaime had the *intention* to help but was unable.  There is no real *conditional* here, although it can be expressed as an *if* statement:

> If Jaime didn't have to work, he **would have helped** you.

"Would helped" is never grammatical.  If talking about a conditional future event you can say something like:

> Jamie **would help** you if he doesn't have to work.

More information: [Everyday grammar: Could Have, Would Have, and Should Have](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-could-have-should-have-would-have/3391128.html)

Comment: +1 for the answer and figuring out the issue. The question that rises now is that how can't we look upon "would" as a past tense modal while it's the past version of "will", and do you think this sentence is not correct too: *She could go to any college she wanted to.*

Comment: @Abbasi  I'm not sure I understand your second question.  "Would helped" is not grammatical because that's not how you conjugate the past tense of "will help".  What exactly do you want to say?

Comment: My second question is: do you think this sentence is not correct too: **She could go to any college she wanted to.**?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.  From her perspective, in the future, going to college, she **wanted** to go to that college.  Native speakers say things like that all the time.

Comment: To summary, you say the above sentence, for example, has nothing to the past, and it's about the future, yeah? What about this please:"*She can go to any college she wants to.*"

Comment: @Abbasi  "could" is not *always* the past form of "can", e.g. "Could I have a glass of water, please" or "If only I could meet her, I know we'd fall in love."   [More info](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/could-can-and-would).  This is why it's not clear what, specifically, you want to say, because in the context of your example "could" indicates a current potential, not a past potential.  But you should probably ask that as a separate question.